# Sort values from sting to map groovy

Tags: groovy

I have a simple task but I stuck with logic.

I have

```
def setType = "test.1gb, test.2gb, test.4gb, nontest.1gb, nontest.4gb, stage.10gb"
def rep = "1, 2"
```

I need to sort it to map, I use `switch case` with `for`. But I wouldn't say I like this solution as it is not flexible. If I add a new type, with this I need to edit switch case construction.

I plan to use for loop, but I miss how to add info to map correctly and think should I use loop. Maybe there is a better way?
My try, but there is problem

```
def test = [:]
for(type in setType.split(', ')){       
    for(r in rep.split(', ')){

test += "${type.split('\\.')}":[ size: type, rep: r, msg: "hello" ]
  }
}
```

How can I build map fast to get next?

```
def test = [
test: [[size:"test.1gb", rep:1, msg:"something"], [size:"test.1gb", rep:2, msg:"something]],
nontest:[[size:"nontest.1gb",rep:1, msg:"something"], [size:"nontest.1gb",  rep:2, msg:"something]]
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% what you mean, but something like this?

```
def setType = "test.1gb, test.2gb, test.4gb, nontest.1gb, nontest.4gb, stage.10gb"
def rep = "1, 2"

def result = setType.split(', ')                               // Split the setType string
        .groupBy { it.split('\\.').head() }                    // Group by the first part of the word
        .collectEntries { key, values ->                       // Then collect a map
    def elements = [values, rep.split(', ').toList()]
        .combinations()                                        // Get all combinations of the prefixed word and the rep values
        .collect {                                             // Collect them into a list
            [ size: it[0], rep: it[1] as int, msg: 'Hello' ]   // Where each combination makes a map
        }
    [key, elements]                                            // The result map has the first part of the word as the key
}

assert result == [
    test:[
        [size:'test.1gb', rep:1, msg:'Hello'],
        [size:'test.2gb', rep:1, msg:'Hello'],
        [size:'test.4gb', rep:1, msg:'Hello'],
        [size:'test.1gb', rep:2, msg:'Hello'],
        [size:'test.2gb', rep:2, msg:'Hello'],
        [size:'test.4gb', rep:2, msg:'Hello']
    ],
    nontest:[
        [size:'nontest.1gb', rep:1, msg:'Hello'],
        [size:'nontest.4gb', rep:1, msg:'Hello'],
        [size:'nontest.1gb', rep:2, msg:'Hello'],
        [size:'nontest.4gb', rep:2, msg:'Hello']
    ],
    stage:[
        [size:'stage.10gb', rep:1, msg:'Hello'],
        [size:'stage.10gb', rep:2, msg:'Hello']
    ]
]
```